# ISC-DHCP-Server Crash without any error messages

Tags: networking, dhcp

I have two server machines with ubuntu 22.04 LTS. One is the master, the secondary is standby.
Both server serve NTP service, Bind9 services and DHCP services (bind9 & DHCP additionally providing DDNS)
The master server strungle with isc-dhcp-server, the secondary not.

The log messages pointed me to problems with system-resolved services, but after some testings, that was not the problem. Some tests points me to bind9 configurations like "ddnssec-validation", but all that is not the problem.
The log messages of failing isc-dhcp-server gives "code=exited, status=1/FAILURE", Journalctl tells me the isc-dhcp-server was stopped. That all.
Manually restarting the DHCP server works without any error.

At least i was able to solve the problem by holding the start of isc-dhcp-server back:

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/sleep 5
```

My idea is, if the NTP server is not online and the DHCP server starts, the time difference between primary and secondary DHCP server is to big and master server stops.

If i had a very special configuration, that would explain the situation.  But a standard config with NTP, Bind9, DHCP ?

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: I would advice that you replace the deprecated ISC- DHCP with [Kea DHCP](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy-updates/kea).

Comment: In the case of KEA i need "hot standby" configuration, so the hook library. Is the apt source "apt install kea" containing the hook library per default?

Comment: I tried to use kea. The standard config works so fare. But, i failed due to the kea-cntrl-agent configuration. I need this working well, because my unterstanding is, the control agent is needed to control a HA featured DHCP server pair. Then i saw, the standard Ubuntu apt source offer KEA 2.02, official documentation is KEA 2.2. Yes, where are "cloud smith" repositories, but that need more deeply knowledge to handle that, then i have.